# Site dinâmico com múltiplas páginas de resultados

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estou fazendo um projeto de um site dinâmico na faculdade e queria saber como montar aquelas páginas de resultado com primeira, segunda páginas e assim por diante sem criar novos arquivos `.php` .

Por exemplo:

Tenho um site de notícias, quando o usuário clicar em uma temática, o site será redirecionado a uma página com notícias relativas ao assunto e são mostradas no máximo 10 notícias em cada página.

Como eu faço para quando usuário clicar no botão da 2ª página, ele ser redirecionado a uma página com as notícias de 11-20, e assim por diante, na 3ª página as notícias de 21-30...; sem criar um arquivo php para as páginas subsequentes, pois pode se tornar muito grande.

Comment: Pesquise por paginação no site, tem uma diversidade de perguntas e respostas sobre o tema.

Comment: Pessoal, estou reabrindo a pergunta porque é possível respondê-la sem se estender muito, como comprovado pela resposta do Hiago abaixo. Leandro, mesmo assim é recomendado ser mais específico na sua pergunta. Se você já tem o site, seria legal ter incluído na pergunta como você já faz a listagem completa das notícias. Assim o pessoal tem um ponto de partida, entende o que você já sabe, etc. Lembrando ainda que a qualquer momento você pode [edit] suas perguntas para melhorá-las. Obrigado.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você procura por paginação em PHP, antes disso você precisa entender o que é paginação. Paginação de resultado é algo bem simples.

Fazemos  uma busca em determinada tabela do Banco de Dados, e com o resultado da busca,  dividimos o número de registros, por um número especifico para exibir por página.

Por exemplo um total de 200 registros, e nós queremos exibir 20 por página, logo  teremos 200/20 = 10 páginas. Simples,  não? Bom vamos lá para o código então.

> Primeiro realize a conexão ao MySQL:

```
<?php
 $conn = mysql_connect("host","usuario","senha");
 $db = mysql_select_db("bancodedados");
?>
```

> Agora vamos criar a cláusula SQL que deve ser executada:

```
<?php
 $busca = "SELECT * FROM tabelax";
?>
```

> Vamos ao trabalho... Especifique o total de registros a serem exibidos por página:

```
<?php
  $total_reg = "10"; // número de registros por página
?>
```

> Se a página não for especificada a variável "pagina" tomará o valor 1, isso evita de exibir a página 0 de início:

```
<?php
 $pagina=$_GET['pagina'];
 if (!$pagina) {
  $pc = "1";
 } else {
  $pc = $pagina;
 }
?>
```

> Vamos determinar o valor inicial das buscas limitadas:

```
<?php
  $inicio = $pc - 1;
  $inicio = $inicio * $total_reg;
?>
```

> Vamos selecionar os dados e exibir a paginação:

```
<?php
  $limite = mysql_query("$busca LIMIT $inicio,$total_reg");
  $todos = mysql_query("$busca");

  $tr = mysql_num_rows($todos); // verifica o número total de registros
  $tp = $tr / $total_reg; // verifica o número total de páginas

  // vamos criar a visualização
  while ($dados = mysql_fetch_array($limite)) {
    $nome = $dados["nome"];
    echo "Nome: $nome<br>";
  }

  // agora vamos criar os botões "Anterior e próximo"
  $anterior = $pc -1;
  $proximo = $pc +1;
  if ($pc>1) {
    echo " <a href='?pagina=$anterior'><- Anterior</a> ";
  }
  echo "|";
  if ($pc<$tp) {
    echo " <a href='?pagina=$proximo'>Próxima -></a>";
  }
 ?>
```

> Prontinho, nossa  paginação em PHP está criada!
>
> Leia mais em: Paginação em PHP http://www.devmedia.com.br/paginacao-em-php/21972#ixzz3EL04G7wL
>
> Fonte: http://www.devmedia.com.br/paginacao-em-php/21972